# Spring Data JPA child entity missing parent ID after transitive save

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have the following class structure

```
@Entity
@Data // lombok
public class Entity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_details_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "entityDetails")
    private EntityDetails entityDetails;
    
}

@Entity
@Data
public class EntityDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "entityDetails")
    @JsonBackReference(value = "entityDetails")
    private Entity entity;
    
    // Some more fields

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "childEntityDetails")
    private List<Child> childList;
    
}

@Entity
@Data
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_details_id")
    @JsonBackReference(value = "childEntityDetails)
    private EntityDetails entityDetails;
    
}
```

Assume I have an Entity object with the following structure:

Entity{
id: null,
entityDetails: {
id: null,
childList: [
{ id: null, description: "ch1" },
{ id: null, description: "ch2" }
]
}
}

When I call `entityRepository.save(entity)`, all the objects are persisted, but the `Child` table does not have a value for `entity_details_id`. The other values are correct (I do have `Entity.entity_details_id` correctly set), but this one does not work. I'm not sure if I'm missing something or if I'm just doing it wrong.

Comment: try addding `@JoinColumn(name = "entity_details_id")` in EntityDetails  and remove it from `Child ` class

Comment: @silentsudo you cannot have `@JoinColumn` on a `mappedBy` field

Comment: of course by remove association